# user variables in mysql update statement

Tags: mysql, sql-update, user-variables

Let `t` be a mysql table and `n` be an integer column in it. I would be interested if the following query can be modified so that the expression `n - 10` is calculated only once.

```
UPDATE t SET n = if(n - 10 < 1, 1, n - 10) WHERE n = 5;
```

The query does not make sense, I know, but I need to use the same pattern in the real application where values `10` and `5` would be php variables.

Comment: What do you mean by calculated only once exactly?

Comment: Why do you care if it is. It will be millions of times faster that actually writing the result to the DB.

Comment: Well, now it is calculated twice (for every occurrence in the if). I want the n-10 expression to be there just once - in an assignment to a user variable like this: @tmp := n - 10. But I do not know the exact syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allright, i have finally found the right syntax. The parentheses around `@tmp := n - 10` are crucial.

```
UPDATE t SET n = if((@tmp := n - 10) < 1, 1, @tmp) WHERE n = 5;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to do this exact thing and adding the parentheses is what made it work.

Answer (score -1):

You can just do such logic in php:

```
$value = $n - 10;
$value = $value < 1 ? 1 : $value;
$sql = "UPDATE t SET n = $value WHERE n = $n";
```

Comment: Thank you, but I might have oversimplified my example. In fact, I need to derive the resulting value of n based on other columns in table.